# Kotlin type mismatch List<Any> and List<Comparable<{com.cognitect.transit.Symbol & com.cognitect.transit.Keyword}>?>

Tags: kotlin, type-mismatch, covariant

```
 fun serialize(aList: List<Any>)
```

When I call serialize with a List containing Symbol and Keyword, the compiler complains

type mismatch:

```
Require List<Any>
Found: List<Comparable<{Symbol & Keyword}>?>
```

Shouldn't List be covariant?

how can I construct a type signature to match what the compiler expects `List<Comparable<{Symbol & Keyword}>?>`

The compiler expects the type `List<Comparable<{Symbol & Keyword}>?>` but that is not valid kotlin syntax

Comment: `fun serialize(aList: List<*>)` ?

Answer (score 6):

You have to make `serialize()` to accept `List<Any?>` instead since your `Comparable` type is nullable.

```
fun serialize(aList: List<Any?>) {}
```

If you want it to accept `List<Comparable<{Symbol & Keyword}>?>`, you have to make use of where-clause to provide multiple upper bounds:

```
fun <T> serialize(aList: List<Comparable<T>?>) where T: Symbol, T: Keyword {}
```